# Adding settings to settings.py - Django

Tags: django

I'm following this Django Tutorial to add photos to my Django webpage. It says to put the following codes into my settings.py. However, I'm sort of confused because I know the two "span class" lines are definitely not Python codes. Therefore, does anyone know what I should do? Do I just include the two Python codes instead?

```
span class="hljs-comment"> # Base url to serve media files</span>
MEDIA_URL = <span class="hljs-string">'/media/'</span>

<span class="hljs-comment"> # Path where media is stored</span>
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, <span class="hljs-string">'media/'</span>)
```

Thanks in advancd!

Comment: If you're using Django > 3.1, it should be `MEDIA_URL = '/media/` and `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'`

Comment: @xyres Thanks for the response. Do I just need to include those lines then?

Comment: Yes. The tutorial also seems outdated because newer django versions don't use `os.path`. They've switched to pathlib. So, `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')` is now just `BASE_DIR / 'media'`.

Comment: I see. Also, may I ask you what MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT are for? I just saw my friend already had ```STATIC_URL = '/static/' ```, ```MEDIA_URL = '/images/' ```, ```STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR / 'static' ]``` and ```MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images' ``` included in settings.py. Therefore, I'm guessing I can just leave it as how it was?

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT` is the **path of the folder** where django will keep files **uploaded by the user**. `MEDIA_URL` is the **url path** where django will **serve** those uploaded files. Read more at the settings page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#media-url